# Receive information once server updated from asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net. I started learning webapi then later I wish to learn the mvc and spa.

I am developing sample api that can be accessed from 2 kinds of desktop application.

App1 will use post request to update the data using api. and App2 will use get request (run every 30 sec) to get the updated information.

Is there anyway sever can send a message for App2 so that it can get the updated data without having check server for every 30sec ?

At present I running a dispatcher timer to send request periodically with 30 sec delay.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This could be a use for [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr). That would push a message to App2 without the need for polling.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out